# Show HTML class on first tab when you do not know which tab will display first as it is dependent on whether data exists in that field

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I have a web page with tabbed content. The information for each tab is pulled from a database. The tab only displays if content exists. The JS requires `class="active"` to be set on the first tab to allow it to load and also to change the colour of the tab to show it is the active tab.

The problem I have is that I don't know which tab will be first, as there may not be any information for the first tab, so it will not display and it will be tab 2 or 3 that will show first.

How can I say 'make this tab have `class="active"` if it is first'?

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="filters">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-1">Content 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-2">Content 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-3">Content 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg active" id="uniquename-tab-1">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
</article>
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-2">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
</article>
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-3">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
</article>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function tabs($container) {
    $container.each(function() {
        $('.tabs > li > a', $container).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            $('.tabs > li', $container).removeClass('active');
            $('.tab-content', $container).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $("#"+tab_id, $container).addClass('active');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you have a code example?

Comment: HTML<nav class="filters">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-1">Content 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-2">Content 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-3">Content 3</a></li>         
</ul>
</nav>  
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg active" id="uniquename-tab-1"> 
<h1>Content 1</h1> 
</article>
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-2"> 
<h1>Content 2</h1> 
</article>
<article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-3">
<h1>Content 3</h1> 
</article>

Comment: Javascript

function tabs($container) {
  $container.each(function() {
   $('.tabs > li > a', $container).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $('.tabs > li', $container).removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-content', $container).removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $("#"+tab_id, $container).addClass('active');
   });
  });
 }

Comment: Oo man x) Add your code in your post with the edit function for more clarity

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry  - First post

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help and http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: <nav class="filters"> <ul class="tabs"> <li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-1">Content 1</a></li> <li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-2">Content 2</a></li> <li><a href="#" data-tab="uniquename-tab-3">Content 3</a></li> </ul> </nav> <article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg active" id="uniquename-tab-1"> <h1>Content 1</h1> </article> <article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-2"> <h1>Content 2</h1> </article> <article class="tab-content has-aside wysiwyg" id="uniquename-tab-3"> <h1>Content 3</h1> </article>

Comment: oh dear - im not doing too well. Submitted that in error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.tabs li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
```

Comment: More explanation would be helpful here. I'm also not sure this will work, this will probably always add `active` to the first `li` in the  DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Bootstrap. If so, I had a similar problem and added a call to the tab function, as stated in the [usage section of their doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tabs a:first").tab('show');
}
```